# My program counts the number of characters correctly but not of the words nor lines. What is the problems?

Tags: c

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "function.h"

int main()
{
    int nl, nw, nc;
    nl = nw = nc = 0;
    char filename[100];

    printf("ENTER FILE NAME: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("OPEN FAIL");
        exit(0);
    }

    nc = character(fp);
    nw = word(fp);
    nl = line(fp);

    printf("number of characters: %d\n", nc);
    printf("number of words: %d\n", nw);
    printf("number of lines: %d\n", nl);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

character.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int character(FILE *fp)
{
    int nc = 0;
    char ch;
    while((ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if(ch != ' ' && ch != '\t' && ch != '\n' && ch != '\0')
        {
            nc++;
        }
    }
    return nc;
}
```

word.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int word(FILE *fp)
{
    int nw = 0;
    char ch;
    while((ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\0')
        {
            nw++;
        }
    }
    return nw;
}
```

line.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int line(FILE *fp)
{
    int nl = 0;
    char ch;
    while((ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if((ch == '\n' || ch == '\0'))
        {
            nl += 1;
        }
    }
    return nl;
}
```

function.h

```
int line(FILE *fp);
int word(FILE *fp);
int character(FILE *fp);
```

execution results

```
ENTER FILE NAME: test.txt  
number of characters: 36  
number of words: 0  
number of lines: 0
```

My program counts the number of characters correctly but not of the words nor lines.
It seems strange to me because I think that the basic structure of codes for word and line counter shouldn't be so different from that for the characters.

I think that I only have to change the conditions of the `if` when I count the numbers of words and lines.

Most of all, at least, the program should give me some number other than mere zeros since the text file definitely contains spaces and new lines.

What do you think the problems here?

FYI the text file I used for testing is

```
test test test  
test test test  
test test test
```

Comment: Consider adding [rewind()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind) after each "count", to reset the file pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have called the `character` function, the file is at its end. The next attempt to read from the file will result in `EOF`.

You need to [*seek*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) back to the beginning again if you want to start reading it all over.

---

On another couple of notes, first remember that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) return an **`int`**, which is rather important for the comparison against the `int` value `EOF`.

Secondly you don't need three different function and three different loops. You can count all statistics in one single loop.

Comment: Thanx. I was completely unware of the rewind even though I've learned it.
I know I can do it in a single loop but the exercise required me to do it in separate codes.
Actually, the  purpose of the exercise was to get one used to the use of the Makefile and that's why it required unnecessarily more codes.